# Titanium: Saving info through app.properties

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, titanium

I have an assignment to do and I am a bit confused with saving information and retrieving it.

A few different things:

1. I have a few textfields(Name, location, age) and I want to be able to save the information written and retreview it once the app is run again.
2. I want the app to remember what was the last screen run.
3. How to set a "first time app launch" ex. first time app is launch a profile option is given where then the 2nd time it would skip right away to the main screen because the information has already been provided.

Appreciate your help so much, thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to add the code, although I don't think its important. Because I think my questions are relative to the window names (profileWin, settingsWin, and catWin) and txtfields like firstNameTXF, ageTXF.
I tried using Titanium.App.Properties.setString("firstName", firstNameTXF.value) , which should save the data, but where? And then recalling it using firstNameTXF.value = Titanium.App.Properties.getString("firstName", 1);

Comment: what are you using alloy or classic version?

Comment: I am using alloy @Swanand

Comment: Not sure if that worked properly @Swanand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To save and retrieve values (if only 3 values) use Properties. To Know more about Properties here are the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties).

2.To know which is the last opened window visit [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112012/titanium-saving-the-state-of-the-last-window-viewed/26138500#26138500).

3.To check if its first time app launch do something like this :

```
    if(Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('firsttime')){
      //Code for second and subsequent launch
    }else{
      //first launch
      //add your code for first launch
      //finally

      Ti.App.Properties.setString("firsttime", "true");
    }
```

Comment: You should use `setBool` if you are saving a Boolean. `Ti.App.Properties.setString("firsttime", "false")` may pass the if statement too.

Comment: NOPE, its not needed, if you will look into the code,i have used `hasProperty` function to check, this will only return if the Property Exist or not(Boolean Value).As for only the first time this Property will not Exist.

Comment: I see, I thought that's `getString` ,but anyway I personally would do it in a different way.

Comment: can you show as an answer how you will do it? i would like to see your approach.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, it has helped. Thanks a lot @Dragon